# OpenStack: VMs inside my private networks cannot ping VMs in my public network, but VMs in my public network can ping VMs in my private network

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm learning OpenStack and I am trying to create the following architecture:

Two private networks: `A` and `B` (Network Type: `vxlan`)
One subnet inside each private network: `SUB_A(192.168.1.0/24)`, `SUB_B(10.0.0.0/24)`

One public network: `public` (Network Type: `flat`, Physical Network: `public`)
One subnet inside my public network: `SUB_PUBLIC(172.24.4.0/24)`

One router connecting it all together, `R`.

One VM connected to each subnet
`VM1` -> `SUB_A`
`VM2` -> `SUB_B`
`VM3` -> `SUB_PUBLIC`

These are the step I used to create the architecture:

-Created the networks and their subnets, with `DHCP` activated.
-Created the router `R`, set it as `external gateway` of network `public` and enabling `SNAT`
-Attached `SUB_A` to `R`
-Attached `SUB_B` to `R`
-Created `VM1` connected to network `A`
-Created `VM2` connected to network `B`
-Created `VM3` connected to network `public`
-Allocated and associated two floating IP address from `public` pool, one for `VM1` and one for `VM2`

The result:

I am able to ping `VM1`/`VM2` **from** `VM3` with their respective floating IP addresses.
I am able to ping `VM1`/`VM2` with their private IPs **from**  `VM1`/`VM2`

I am **not** able to ping `VM3` **from** `VM1`/`VM2`
I am **not** able to ping `VM1`/`VM2` **from** `VM1`/`VM2` with their floating IP addresses.

At this point, I'm not sure what I am missing. I would like to understand what is going on.

Comment: It's as if SNAT were not enabled. Can you double-check? If it's a centralized router (the default), go to the controller, create a shell in the router's network namespace and add `ip a`, `ip r` and `iptables-save` to the question. Also, how was the cloud created, and (assuming ML2) which mechanism and type drivers are configured?

Answer (score 0):

The security groups ended up being the culprit. The default security groups used by the VMs had to have egress and ingress rules to allow ICMP traffic to go through! I had already verified but I didn't pay enough attention to it's configuration. The source traffic especially had to be correct! I had it set to an incorrect source, which explained why traffic would never go through.